Why is the input and output of a P.C function bounded by the number of steps?
In Turing Computability by Soare,definition 1.6.17 states the following:
We write $\phi_{e,s}(x) = y$ if $x, y, e < s$ and $y$ is the output
of $\phi_e(x)$ in $< s$ steps of the Turing program $P_e$. If such a $y$ exists we say $\phi_{e,s}(x)$ converges and we write $\phi_{e,s}(x)\downarrow$, and diverges $\phi_{e,s}(x)\uparrow$ otherwise.
To my understanding, this would mean that the identity function Turing program diverges on every input, as the identity Turing program would simply output whatever was on the input tape without making any steps. Hence, $s$ would always be zero and there would be no $x$ or $y$ less than zero to satisfy the definition above.
However, it is obvious that the identity function is computable and its corresponding Turing program would halt on every input with some output on its tape. Why is the definition like this? I am having trouble wrapping my head around this.

If the program halts in $0$ steps, then it halts in $<s$ steps for any $s>0.$ Thus for any $s > \max(x, 0)$ we have $\phi_{e,s}(x)\downarrow= x$.
The point of the parameter $s$ isn't that it's the number of steps the program runs for. It is a bound that we intend to keep raising to allow the program to run longer (if it hasn't halted yet) in order to get closer to the program's actual behavior. We have $\phi_e(x) \downarrow =y$ if and only if there is some (possibly very large) $s$ such that $\phi_{e,s}(x)\downarrow = y.$
